# Is it posible to find the eigen vector in this particular case?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have the following system:
$$\begin{cases}\dot x=2x+by \\ \dot y=x+2y\end{cases}$$
They ask to find the phase plane for different values of b. However I encounter several problems with this.

First what I did, was to deal with this like a regular matrix:
$$A=\begin{pmatrix} 2 & b \\ 1 & 2\end{pmatrix}$$
Finding the eigen values: $(A-\lambda I_2)=0$, where $\lambda=1\pm \sqrt{b-3}$. Problems start when I want to find the eigen vectors. $(A-\lambda I_2)(x,y)^\tau=(0,0)^\tau$.So for $\lambda=1+\sqrt{b-3}$ we get:
$$\begin{cases}(1+\sqrt{b-3})x+by=0 [1]\\ x+(1+\sqrt{b-3})y=0 [2]\end{cases}$$
From [2] we have that $x=(1+\sqrt{b-3})y$, and after some calculations that I hope I didn't messed up, $\sqrt{b-3}y=(2-b)y$. Obviously we don't want to use the trivial case (0,0), but I don't know how to get the information from this.

I assume this is when the cases for b begin, but I don't know if that's correct.

Answer (score 1):

One nice trick in the 2D case: you can really just work with one equation or the other, since the two are dependent anyway (provided you've computed the eigenvalue correctly). Actually, you didn't calculate the eigenvalue correctly: the trace of your matrix is $4$ so the eigenvalues must sum to $4$, which yours do not. You should have $\lambda^2-4\lambda+(4-b)=0$ (here $4-b$ is the determinant). So I guess the eigenvalues are $2 \pm \sqrt{b}$.

Anyway, having found the eigenvalue and set up the system, you should find that there are fewer $b$s in the second equation than in the first, so it is slightly more convenient to use that one. We will get a one-parameter family of solutions, so we can choose $y=1$ arbitrarily to get $x=\lambda-2$. There was nothing special about $y=1$, I could've used any other nonzero value of $y$ or even any nonzero value of $x$ in order to choose my eigenvector.

You get a second eigenvector analogously except when you have a double eigenvalue, which will occur when $16-4(4-b)=0$. (So I guess $b=0$.) Then you will need a generalized eigenvector.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. When you say _set up the system_, does that mean solving $(A-\lambda I_2)\bar x=\bar0$?
And when you say _...there are fewer bs in the second equation than in the first, so it is... convenient to use that one_, that means that you could use  only one ecuation to find all the information you need?

Comment: @BadlySunburned 1. Yes. 2. In the 2D case, yes. That's because the system consists of two equations which are dependent, by the very way in which you constructed everything. Since they are dependent, using both equations adds no additional information compared to using just one. Put another way, you can cancel one equation entirely by adding a multiple of the other one. In more than 2 dimensions this becomes less useful.